# Putting value from Combobox Item to Textbox in vb.net "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Main
    Dim Adult As Integer = 495 'Adult as Integer
    Dim Senior As Integer = 395 'Senior as Integer

    Private Sub Combo() 'New created Sub
        Dim Aval = Combad.Text 'Aval as Combo box Adult
        Dim Sval = Comse.Text 'Sval as Combo box Senior


        Textpay.Text = Adult * Aval + Senior * Sval 'Adding up the total of both Combo Box's Value
    End Sub
Private Sub Combad_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combad.SelectedIndexChanged
        Combo() 'Private Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub Comse_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Comse.SelectedIndexChanged
        Combo() 'Private Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't multiply `String`s (imagine trying yourself to multiply `grape * banana`). Convert them to `Double`s before attempting arithmetic functions on them.

Comment: Why would you think that converting an empty `String` to a `Double` would be possible in the first place?  Why are you trying to do arithmetic with `Strings` in the first place, especially when they may not actually represent numbers?  If you want to do arithmetic then you need to do it with numbers, so you need to make sure that you have numbers.  Obviously one of the values you're using doesn't represent a number.  You need to investigate and debug your code to find out which one and why.

Comment: Adding comments is good when it clarifies or adds important information. I am afraid your comments do neither. They would be considered clutter. I did the same thing when I first started.

Comment: @Mary, I think the OP might have those comments where they are for debugging. I mean he's trying to convince himself that the code works

Answer (score 0):

First check if your combobox is empty or not cause you will get an error if it is (by using `if Aval <> string.empty`)  second of all you need to check if the combobox is a number, you can use `If Integer.TryParse(Aval, Nothing)`. Use `AndAlso` if you want to check both at the same time `if Aval <> string.empty AndAlso Integer.TryParse(Aval, Nothing)`

Comment: IsNumeric from VB6 has been replaced by the .TryParse methods in .net.

Comment: Yes, but when you try to code in C#  (and you will) you will be lost. I don't think the C# people want to reference a vb library.  Also, the .TryParse methods were written with improved performance over the old IsNumberic.

Comment: I have no problem using tryparse but i just hate that you have to use a reference for that integer OR doing `If Integer.TryParse(Aval, Nothing) Then`. But if it was changed to improve performance then you are right to use it and i will change the answer to that..

Comment: Presumably, you are going to use the converted value so the "extra" reference is not wasted.

Answer (score 0):

You parse the String values in the .Text property with .TryParse. The method will return True and assign the Integer value to the provided variable if the conversion is possible.

```
    Private Adult As Integer = 495
    Private Senior As Integer = 395

    Private Sub Combo()
        Dim Aval As Integer
        Dim Sval As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(Combad.Text, Aval) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(Comse.Text, Sval) Then
            Textpay.Text = (Adult * Aval + Senior * Sval).ToString
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Both drop down boxes must display a number.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is the complete code that I just tested.

```
Private Adult As Integer = 495
Private Senior As Integer = 395


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({1, 2, 3, 4})
    ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({1, 2, 3, 4})
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Combo()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Combo()
End Sub

Private Sub Combo()
    Dim Aval As Integer
    Dim Sval As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(ComboBox1.Text, Aval) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(ComboBox2.Text, Sval) Then
        TextBox1.Text = (Adult * Aval + Senior * Sval).ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Both drop down boxes must display a number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first combobox is working but, when I checked both at the same time it say "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." I have indexed numbers 1 - 20 inside the combobox. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChikitsGarots How did you check both at the same time?

Comment: I tried your example. it says "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." Then I removed one combobox, it worked. Still thanks for helping me.

Comment: In the if statement part Ma'am/Sir

Comment: Did you get the MessageBox with the message about "Both drop down..."?

Comment: @ChikitsGarots See the Edit to my answer. I tested the code and it works fine for me.